# Create menu with switch-statement, loop and list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on a Menu where I want to use `switch` and `list` inside the menu choice. I also want to loop this program until the user decides to quit (by choosing the last option in the menu).

I'm stuck because I dont know how to do the loop, or the `list` for the first menu choice. I want the user to be able to add any number of things to the bag, like "cat", "dog", "car", etc.

This is how my code looks at the moment:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                       
        Console.Title = "5";
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        // ________________________________________________________

        Console.WriteLine("\n \t This is your bag!");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [1] to pack things");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [2] to pack things in the outercompartment");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [3] to see packed things");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [4] to quit");
        Console.WriteLine("\t your choice: ");
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        int nr = Convert.ToInt32(str);
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add(str);

        switch (nr)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Write("What would you like to pack?\t");
                str = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix the formatting on your code, please.

Comment: Create a bool before all your code set to false, surrond all your code with `while(!yourVar)` and finally if the user selects the fourth option set the variable to true.

Comment: How do you quit a bag?

Comment: @DarrenYoung With the 4 key.

Comment: @DarrenYoung Not the answer i really need, please.. its a program.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Haha

Comment: Look at the comment from @Gusman.  That's a good approach for your loop.

Comment: @DarrenYoung i tried it, but my whole pc kinda freezed when using that one?

Comment: Okey i did like @Gusman said and it worked, thanks. but how do i make it so i can add more than one item on Menu Choice 1 ?

Comment: @AlexG That's another completely different question...

Comment: @AlexG It is another question as Gusman says, but you could, for example use a comma separated string as the input and then split that to get the individual items.  There are many other ways though including using a 2nd menu.  Try something then come back with a specific question with relevant code if you can't get it to work.

Comment: @Gusman yeah i know, but is this possible? as i tried doing it with the " STR+=Console.readline(); it didnt work. i also want menu choice 3 to display all the packed items, but i need to do something with the list?

Comment: @Alex I would create a sepparate function for each submenu, just present any option you want and use the same technique on each of these, then from your main switch you just launch the correct function. Also, S.O. is not the place for these kind of questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @Alex you added the string *before* it had it's value, instead of `str = Console.ReadLine()` use `items.Add(Console.ReadLine())` but beware, that on a real program would leave the user without any option to cancel the input, and that's not a good idea. Again, if each submenu has complex logic separate it in different functions, it will be more manageable and readable.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

1. Since you give the option to pack the "outer compartment" separately from packing the main bag, create a separate list for this. So I would have `mainCompartment` and `outerCompartment` lists.
2. Wrap your choice options inside a `while` loop, so you can continue asking questions until the user quits. This will require some type of flag, so we know when to quit, so create a Boolean called `allDone` that starts as `false`, then set it to `true` if the user chooses option 4.
3. Do some validation on the user input, to be sure they choose a number from 1 to 4. The easiest way is to check the result of `int.TryParse`, since it will return false if the input isn't an int, and combine this with the bounds check that the number is from 1-4.
4. Put the real code for getting items into the bag and displaying bag contents into separate functions, and then call them from the `switch` statement. This will make your main body of code much easier to read.
5. Put the code that asks the user to enter items into a loop, and give them some keyword to type when they're done. This word will become the flag to exit the loop.

Here's how the main code might look when finished:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.Title = "5";
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;

    List<string> outerCompartment = new List<string>();
    List<string> mainCompartment = new List<string>();

    bool allDone = false;

    while (!allDone)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nThis is your bag!");
        Console.WriteLine("[1] to pack things in the main compartment");
        Console.WriteLine("[2] to pack things in the outer compartment");
        Console.WriteLine("[3] to see packed things");
        Console.WriteLine("[4] to quit");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your choice: ");

        int choice;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice) || choice < 1 || choice > 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Enter a number from 1 to 4: ");
        }

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                GetItemsAndAddToCompartment(mainCompartment, "main");
                Console.Clear();
                break;
            case 2:
                GetItemsAndAddToCompartment(outerCompartment, "outer");
                Console.Clear();
                break;
            case 3:
                DisplayCompartmentContents(mainCompartment, "Main");
                DisplayCompartmentContents(outerCompartment, "Outer");
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("All done. Have a great trip!");
                allDone = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And the two helper functions that are called by the main code:

```
static void GetItemsAndAddToCompartment(List<string> compartment, string compartmentName)
{
    if (compartment == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(compartment));
    Console.WriteLine($"Enter items to add to {compartmentName} compartment below. Type 'done' when finished.");

    int counter = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write($"Enter item #{counter++}: ");
        string item = Console.ReadLine();
        if (item.Equals("done", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) break;
        compartment.Add(item);
    }
}

static void DisplayCompartmentContents(List<string> compartment, string compartmentName)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{compartmentName} compartment contents");
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
    if (compartment == null || !compartment.Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[No items in this compartment]");
    }
    else
    {
        compartment.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ! okey i'll totally look into this , thank you for the cool tips! :O

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintMenu();
        List<string> lBag = new List<string>();
        bool bQuit = false;
        int iChoice = -1;
        string sIn = string.Empty;

        while (!bQuit)
        {
            sIn = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!Int32.TryParse(sIn, out iChoice) || !(iChoice >= 1 && iChoice <= 3))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t Invalid input. Try again:");
                PrintMenu();
                continue;
            }

            switch (iChoice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("\t Insert the item you want to add:");
                    lBag.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("\t Item added successfully.");
                    PrintMenu();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\t Current bag: [{0}]\n", string.Join(", ", lBag)));
                    PrintMenu();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("\t Quitting...");
                    bQuit = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void PrintMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n Please choose one of the options below:");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [1] Add item to bag");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [2] Display the bag");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [3] Quit");
    }
}
```

Comment: I will definatly try it, Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

The real answer: Make a UI with buttons and popups ;-)

A fix that will get a me a lot of downvotes (Warning: 'this solution considered harmful...')

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                       
        Console.Title = "5";
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        // ________________________________________________________
        loop:
        Console.WriteLine("\n \t This is your bag!");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [1] to pack things");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [2] to pack things in the outercompartment");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [3] to see packed things");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [4] to quit");
        Console.WriteLine("\t your choice: ");
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        int nr = Convert.ToInt32(str);
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add(str);

        switch (nr)
        {
            case 1:
                packing:
                Console.Write("What would you like to pack? [QUIT for menu]\t");
                str = Console.ReadLine();
                if (str=="QUIT") goto loop;
                items.add(str);
                Console.WriteLine("You packed a " + str);
                goto packing;
                break;
            case 4:
                goto quitloop;

        }

        Console.ReadKey();
        goto loop;
    }
quitloop:
}
```

Not tested of course.

Also this is a terrible lazy fix ... you can convert this do do, while, etc.

Comment: goto?? yes that's first -1.

Comment: Im still stuck at the loop, it works if its outside and ontop of the title line, but if i put it between { these} on top of the title line the loop works but maybe not as it should ?

Comment: `this solution considered harmful`  Best not to post solutions that are considered harmful, no?  Let alone ones with goto in simple code.  This can VERY easily be refactored without the gotos.  I'd expect someone with better than 4x the rep of me to know that they should only be used in edge cases...this certainly isn't one of them.

Comment: This is a terrible answer and one that should never be proposed to a beginner.

Comment: Also because I was side tracked with the `goto` statements, I didn't even notice that this code will break if anyone enters something that isn't a number...this really is bad code.

Comment: yep guys after you reach a certain age, you stop caring if strangers on the internet are just too %insult% to get a dry joke. Here's to the ones of you smart enough to have enjoyed half a laugh ;-) take a break and get a cup of coffee.